# How to automatically position R2 and RMSE in facetted ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to automatically position R2 and RMSE in facetted  `ggplot`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65322125/6123824) answer has helped me to put the R2 and RMSE in facetted  `ggplot` manually using the following code

```
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)

summ <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Rsq = R2(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length),
            RMSE = RMSE(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits=2)

p <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point(color="blue",alpha = 1/3) + 
  facet_wrap(Species ~ ., scales="free") +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, fill="black", formula = y ~ x) +
  xlab("Sepal Length") +
  ylab("Petal Length") + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 

# Here we create our annotations data frame.
df.annotations <- data.frame()
# Rsq
df.annotations <- rbind(df.annotations,
                        cbind(as.character(summ$Species),
                              paste("Rsq", summ$Rsq,
                                    sep = " = ")))

# RMSE
df.annotations <- rbind(df.annotations,
                        cbind(as.character(summ$Species),
                              paste("RMSE", summ$RMSE,
                                    sep = " = ")))

# This here is important, especially naming the first column
# Species
colnames(df.annotations) <- c("Species", "label")

df.annotations$x <- rep.int(c(4.5, 5.5, 5.5), times = 2)
df.annotations$y <- c(1.75, 5.0, 6.8,
                      1.7, 4.9, 6.7)


p + geom_text(data = df.annotations,
              mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, label = label))
```

[image]

As you can see from `df.annotations`, I am providing the positions manually. Now how can I automatically position R2 and RMSE in `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically we set `x` and `y` to `-Inf` and `+Inf` in `geom_text()`
then tweak the position with `hjust` and `vjust`.
As we have two rows: Rsq... and RMSE we define `vertical_adjustement` before `geom_text()`

The whole code:

```
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)

summ <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Rsq = R2(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length),
            RMSE = RMSE(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits=2)

p <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point(color="blue",alpha = 1/3) + 
  facet_wrap(Species ~ ., scales="free") +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, fill="black", formula = y ~ x) +
  xlab("Sepal Length") +
  ylab("Petal Length") + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 

# Here we create our annotations data frame.
df.annotations <- data.frame()
# Rsq
df.annotations <- rbind(df.annotations,
                        cbind(as.character(summ$Species),
                              paste("Rsq", summ$Rsq,
                                    sep = " = ")))

# RMSE
df.annotations <- rbind(df.annotations,
                        cbind(as.character(summ$Species),
                              paste("RMSE", summ$RMSE,
                                    sep = " = ")))

# This here is important, especially naming the first column
# Species
colnames(df.annotations) <- c("Species", "label")


vertical_adjustment = ifelse(grepl("Rsq",df.annotations$label),1.5,3)


p + geom_text(data=df.annotations,aes(x=-Inf,y=+Inf,label=label),
              hjust = -0.1, vjust = vertical_adjustment, size=3.5)
```

[image]

**How to do:**

Remove this part at the end:

```
df.annotations$x <- rep.int(c(4.5, 5.5, 5.5), times = 2)
df.annotations$y <- c(1.75, 5.0, 6.8,
                      1.7, 4.9, 6.7)


p + geom_text(data = df.annotations,
              mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, label = label))
```

replace by:

```
vertical_adjustment = ifelse(grepl("Rsq",df.annotations$label),1.5,3)


p + geom_text(data=df.annotations,aes(x=-Inf,y=+Inf,label=label),
              hjust = -0.1, vjust = vertical_adjustment, size=3.5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is just what I was wanted. Can you please explain what `ifelse(grepl("Rsq",df.annotations$label),1.5,3)` part is doing? Specially the values 1.5 and 3 is doing?

Comment: with `grpl ` we check in label column if there is a string "Rsq" -> if true then put it on vertical position 1.5, else in this case RMSE on vertical position 3

Comment: Suppose I want to add another line i.e. Rsq, RMSE and NSE, then how this part `ifelse(grepl("Rsq",df.annotations$label),1.5,3)` should be changed?

Comment: With `ifelse` you get only true and false to distinguish with more elements we should use `case_when`.  This would imply that in your df.annotations$label column there are more then two possiblites. Maybe you can start a new question referring to this question and I can show!

Comment: I have asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67802720/how-to-automatically-position-multiple-model-evaluation-parameters-in-facetted-g). Kindly visit that.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite what you're looking for, but you could move the Rsq & RMSE in to the facet titles e.g.

```
# copy species, and change its values to include the Rsq and RMSE. Levels should match if both grouped alphabetically
iris$Species2 <- iris$Species
levels(iris$Species2) <- sprintf("%s \n Rsq=%s \n RMSE=%s",
                                levels(iris$Species), summ$Rsq, summ$RMSE)

# change facet wrap to Species2
p <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point(color="blue",alpha = 1/3) + 
  facet_wrap(~Species2, scales="free") +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, fill="black", formula = y ~ x) +
  xlab("Sepal Length") +
  ylab("Petal Length") + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 
p
```

Comment: No, I don't want to move the Rsq & RMSE into the facet titles. I have shown the expected output in my question.

Comment: No worries. I didn't offhand have a solution for that but knew an alternative route so thought I'd share in case it also solved your problem :)