# How to automatically position multiple model evaluation parameters in facetted ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to automatically position multiple model evaluation parameters in facetted `ggplot`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67802079/6123824) answer has helped me to put the R2 and RMSE in facetted `ggplot` automatically using the following code

```
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)

summ <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Rsq = R2(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length),
            RMSE = RMSE(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits=2)

p <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point(color="blue",alpha = 1/3) + 
  facet_wrap(Species ~ ., scales="free") +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, fill="black", formula = y ~ x) +
  xlab("Sepal Length") +
  ylab("Petal Length") + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 

# Here we create our annotations data frame.
df.annotations <- data.frame()

# Rsq
df.annotations <- rbind(df.annotations,
                        cbind(as.character(summ$Species),
                              paste("Rsq", summ$Rsq,
                                    sep = " = ")))

# RMSE
df.annotations <- rbind(df.annotations,
                        cbind(as.character(summ$Species),
                              paste("RMSE", summ$RMSE,
                                    sep = " = ")))

# This here is important, especially naming the first column
# Species
colnames(df.annotations) <- c("Species", "label")


vertical_adjustment = ifelse(grepl("Rsq",df.annotations$label),1.5,3)


p + geom_text(data=df.annotations,aes(x=-Inf,y=+Inf,label=label),
              hjust = -0.1, vjust = vertical_adjustment, size=3.5)
```

[image]
I have calculated NSE using `hydroGOF` package like

```
library(hydroGOF)

summ <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Rsq = R2(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length),
            RMSE = RMSE(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length),
            NSE = NSE(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits=2)
```

Added the NSE to the `df.annotations` dataframe like

```
# NSE
df.annotations <- rbind(df.annotations,
                        cbind(as.character(summ$Species),
                              paste("NSE", summ$NSE,
                                    sep = " = ")))
```

Now, how can I place multiple model evaluation parameters in facetted `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the new part using `case_when` from `dplyr` package for aligning vertically:

```
library(dplyr)

vertical_adjustment = case_when(grepl("Rsq",df.annotations$label) ~ 1.5,
                                grepl("RMSE",df.annotations$label) ~ 3,
                                grepl("NSE",df.annotations$label) ~ 4.5)

p + geom_text(data=df.annotations,aes(x=-Inf,y=+Inf,label=label),
              hjust = -0.1, vjust = vertical_adjustment, size=3.5)
```

[image]

**The whole code:**

```
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)
library(hydroGOF)

summ <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Rsq = R2(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length),
            RMSE = RMSE(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length),
            NSE = NSE(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits=2)


p <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point(color="blue",alpha = 1/3) + 
  facet_wrap(Species ~ ., scales="free") +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, fill="black", formula = y ~ x) +
  xlab("Sepal Length") +
  ylab("Petal Length") + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 

p
# Here we create our annotations data frame.
df.annotations <- data.frame()
# Rsq
df.annotations <- rbind(df.annotations,
                        cbind(as.character(summ$Species),
                              paste("Rsq", summ$Rsq,
                                    sep = " = ")))

# RMSE
df.annotations <- rbind(df.annotations,
                        cbind(as.character(summ$Species),
                              paste("RMSE", summ$RMSE,
                                    sep = " = ")))

df.annotations <- rbind(df.annotations,
                        cbind(as.character(summ$Species),
                              paste("NSE", summ$NSE,
                                    sep = " = ")))

# This here is important, especially naming the first column
# Species
colnames(df.annotations) <- c("Species", "label")


library(dplyr)

vertical_adjustment = case_when(grepl("Rsq",df.annotations$label) ~ 1.5,
                                grepl("RMSE",df.annotations$label) ~ 3,
                                grepl("NSE",df.annotations$label) ~ 4.5)

p + geom_text(data=df.annotations,aes(x=-Inf,y=+Inf,label=label),
              hjust = -0.1, vjust = vertical_adjustment, size=3.5)
```

Comment: What these `1.5`, `3.5` and `4.5` indicate? How to determine these values?

Comment: vertical alignment. Just change to see. forexample 4.5 to 5.5.